# Why can a GCP service account not impersonate itself?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam

We are currently running a process in a CI pipeline, this CI pipeline deploys resources to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and then invokes a cloud function. One of the scripts that we run as part of this deployment issues this:

```sh
gcloud --impersonate-service-account "$DEPLOYER_SA" functions call "$FUNCTION_NAME" --region "$REGION" --project "$PROJECT_ID" --data {}
```

however it fails with error:

> WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [deployer-dev@redacted-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) Failed to impersonate [deployer-dev@redacted-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com]. Make sure the account that's trying to impersonate it has access to the service account itself and the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role.

In other words the service account being impersonated is the same service account that is running the script (I won't go into why this is the case - there are reasons).

My question is...I'm quite surprised that a service account cannot impersonate itself. Why would it not be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you granted the role Service Account Token Creator to your service account?

You can do this by going to IAM -> Service Accounts -> Select the service account (deployer-dev@redacted-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com) -> Permissions -> Grant Access -> New Members (add the same account deployer-dev@redacted-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com) -> Role add Service Account Token Creator -> Save

Hope this information is helpful to you.

Comment: We've done that for many other accounts but I guess I was thinking we wouldn't have to if the SA being granted was the same SA that the role is being granted upon.

Comment: By the way, not that it really matters, but we grant access using terraform hence https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam#google_service_account_iam_member comes in useful here.